# Case insensitive searching in elasticsearch 6.1.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, wildcard, case-insensitive

I was trying to search the following case

I want to search a name that ends with the particular word. For example:

name : group Test

name : group test

name : group test org

Here is my wild card query

```
"bool" : {
    "must" : [
            {
            "wildcard" : {
                "name.keyword"" : {
                    "wildcard" : "*test",
                    "boost" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It returns me "group test" for case sensitive search

But I need to get both "group Test" and "group test" for case-insensitive search.

my mapping as follows:

```
 "name":{
            "type":"text",
            "fielddata":true
            "fields":{
                "keyword":{
                            "type":"keyword"
                        }
                }
         }
```

Can anyone help me to find out queries in elasticsearch java api or any other way to search it.

Elastic search version 6.1.2

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using lowercase_expanded_terms: false? Take a look at this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3922

Comment: no, I am not using any lowercase_expanded_terms

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to do this with ES configuration as [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/keyword.html) type does not have the [`analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/analyzer.html) property but I found a workaround. Please take a look on this [solution](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/wildcard-case-insensitive-query-string/75050/5):

```
PUT test
{  
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      },
      "normalizer": {
        "lowerasciinormalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "string_as_keyword": {
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "match":   "*_k",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "normalizer": "lowerasciinormalizer"                              
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

PUT test/1/123
{
  "str_k" : "string âgáÈÒU is cool"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "str_k": "*agaeou*"
    }
  }
}
```